# Boolean as a property in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, properties

I'm sure that this has been asked MANY times before, but it's still giving me trouble. I define my class's Boolean property like this:

```
@property(readwrite,assign) BOOL namesVisible;
```

And it doesn't give compiler errors, but it NSLogs as (null). Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm at a loss to what it is.

Comment: Can you post the NSLog statement you're using?  I suspect the format string is wrong if it's outputting "(null)".

Comment: That might be right, because I recently NSLogged in a function inside the class where the boolean is used. I have a UISwitch that is used to change it, and when I NSLog there, the app crashes with no error message. here's what I use for my NSLog:    NSLog(@"namesVisible: %@", optionsViewController2.namesVisible);

Comment: Here's something interesting: When I nslog with %d instead, it outputs a 0 as if it were an object, not a boolean.

Comment: XenElement: You mean it outputs a 0 as if it were an integer, which is what `%d` tells it to expect, and is what a `BOOL` is a kind of. Just passing the `BOOL` value for `%d` is not, strictly speaking, safe, as a `BOOL` is shorter than an `int` and I'm fairly sure that the implementation is allowed to not convert `BOOL` to `int`. That may happen on architectures currently supported by Mac OS X and iOS, but to be safe, you should explicitly cast the value as I showed in my answer, or use the other form I also showed in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BOOLs are just chars, either 0 or 1. As such, you don't need to use a storage keyword in the property declaration, so it should be:

```
@property (readwrite) BOOL namesVisible;
```

Second, when logging a BOOL, use the int format string, %d, or pass in a string:

```
NSLog(@"My Boolean: %d, or %@", object.namesVisible, object.namesVisible ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Comment: Okay great! That worked out, I think both of you ended up being correct, Your answer was just nicer and simpler. The problem was my NSLog and my storage keyword. So cheers, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to log it as an object by using `%@`, and a `BOOL` isn't an object, and your property's value is `NO` and you're lucky.

The last part is because you're only passing a `BOOL` to `NSLog`, but since your format string says to expect an object pointer, it will read a pointer's worth from the argument stack. Since a pointer is bigger than a `BOOL`, it's reading more than you passed it. You're lucky that it got zeroes for all four/eight bytes (your `NO` was only one of them); the result is that it sent its `description` message to `nil`, which returned `nil` for the description string, which prints as “(null)” in the output.

If you'd been unlucky and/or the property's value had been `YES`, it would have read something that *isn't* `nil`, but is nonetheless probably not a pointer to an object that exists. As such, trying to log that would cause a crash, probably of the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` variety. If you'd been unlucky *and* lucky at the same time, you would have printed the description of an actual object, and wondered how the hell your `BOOL` looked like that.

The solution is one of two things:

```
NSLog(@"My Boolean property: %d", (int)[myObject myBooleanProperty]);
```

or:

```
NSLog(@"My Boolean property: %@", [myObject myBooleanProperty] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

The former casts the Boolean value to a full-size `int` and prints that value as such (most probably either 0 or 1), whereas the latter will pass either `@"YES"` or `@"NO"` as the argument depending on the Boolean value. Since NSString literals are (NSString) objects, the `%@` formatter becomes the right one.

Comment: That's a great idea, and it seems to work, only I fear the problem is much deeper. I actually tried doing something with the boolean and it didn't do anything, responding as if it were indeed null, which it is. If I have a method that says do something when the boolean property is true, then the NSLog trick doesn't really help. Unless the boolean isn't actually null, and you're saying it's just returning as that?

Comment: XenElement: As I said, a `BOOL` isn't an object. As such, you can't send messages to it. If it's `NO`, then treating it as an object pointer means you're sending a message to `nil`, with all the lack of results that implies. If it's any other value, then treating it as an object pointer would cause a crash. A `BOOL` can never truly be `NULL`, `nil`, or any other pointer value, because it is not a pointer; however, it can be `NO`, which converts to `NULL`/`nil` when converted to a pointer.

Comment: Ah. So what's the correct way to have a bool that can be set in one view and accessed in another? I assume that it's a property, but obviously I haven't done it correctly.

Comment: XenElement: Incorrect. The property is declared and working fine. It's only your logging that's wrong.

Comment: Yes you were right, the storage keyword was screwing it up for me, and the logging. So thank you, the two answers combined helped.

Comment: XenElement: No, the storage element was just redundant; it wasn't screwing anything up. `assign` is the default, so omitting it vs. having it makes no difference.